# Behavior after pressing a button

Tags: php, html-table, submit, isset

I have a table filled with data from data base submitted through a form. Every time I add some info in the form, this will be displayed in the table below. At the end of each row is a button, say, "delete". If any button is pressed, the respective row is deleted including from the data base.

```
echo "<table>"

while($date=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))//$q is select * from table
{
    echo "<tr><td>{$date['id']}</td><td>{$date['nume']}</td><td>{$date['prenume']}</td><td>{$date['adresa']}</td><td>{$date['datan']}</td><td>{$date['fumator']}</td><form method=\"post\"><td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value='{$date['id']}'><input type=\"submit\" name=\"sterge\" value=\"sterge\"></td></form></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
if(isset($_POST['sterge'])) echo "'sterge' was pressed but also the row was deleted. why?!";
```

No other queries attached to if(isset). Just wanted to see what happens if I press any button and I don't understand why is this happening.

Comment: remove delete action in  your code if u don't want  delete action

Comment: This is the problem. There is no delete action, at least not one "written" by me. I want to understand why the row is deleted just because I pressed a button that basically does nothing but echo some text.

Comment: Do you have 1 form or multiple? It can be the case that when you pressed the button the whole form submitted, leading to a deleted record

Comment: Each button from each row is a "little form". The row where i press "sterge" gets deleted. What do you mean by 'the form being submitted' ? Basically i submit a button. What has it to do with the data base? (except that the hidden field of each of those "little forms" has the value of the column id...)

Comment: i think i got it ...